# No retornar propiedad de schema

Tags: nodejs

Estoy creado un modelo con el módulo de Mongoose, y se trata de un Usuario, pero quiero que al crearlo una propiedad no se devuelva (en este caso la contraseña). Encontre que se puede hacer algo así pero no sirve, la contraseña se sigue enviando en la respuesta. Esta es la función que uso:

```
userSchema.methods.toJson = function() {
    let user = this;
    let userObject = user.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    return userObject;
}
```

Y este es el código entero del modelo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

let roles = {
    values: ['ADMIN_ROLE', 'USER_ROLE'],
    message: '{VALUE} no es un rol valido'
};

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El correo es necesario'],
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La contraseña es necesaria']
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'USER_ROLE',
        enum: roles
    },
    state: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
});

userSchema.methods.toJson = function() {
    let user = this;
    let userObject = user.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    return userObject;
}
user.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{PATH} debe ser único' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

La respuesta en Postman sigue trayendo la contraseña en la respuesta. Lo pude resolver de otra forma, donde tengo el post para generar un nuevo usuario, y en donde como respuesta a ese post devuelvo el schema (pero no quiero devolver la contraseña unicamente), en el metodo Save hago asi antes de devolver la respuesta:

```
usuario.save((err, usuarioDB) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                error: err
            });
        }
        usuarioDB.password = undefined;
        res.json({
            ok: true,
            usuario: usuarioDB
        });
    });
```

Pero lo malo de esto es que lo tengo que hacer en todos los lugares donde consulte un usuario, por lo que quisiera tenerlo en el modelo así no repito código y se que nunca me lo olvido.
Alguna sugerencia de como lo puedo resolver? O por que la función no funciona?
Gracias!

Comment: Te sigue enviando el campo `pasword` porque nunca llamas al método `toJson()`. Para que devuelva el modelo sin el campo sólo debes devolver: `res.json({ ok: true, usuario: usuarioDB.toJson() });`. Así no necesitas hacer el paso previo: `usuarioDB.password = undefined;`. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si queres agregalo como respuesta asi puedo votarla tambien.
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata en vez de crear una transform

```
// especifica la opción del transform
if (!userSchema.options.toObject) userSchema.options.toObject = {};
userSchema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  delete ret.password;
  return ret;
}

// Aqui ya puedes llamar toObject y le quitara el password
usuarioDB.toObject(); // { email: 'sample@sample.com', role: 'some role', state: 'some state'}
```

Aqui puedes leer mas en los docs [Document#toObject and transformations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Y si prefieres hacerlo como lo estas haciendo, trata the utilizar toJSON()

```
 let userObject = user.toJSON();
 delete userObject.password;
 return userObject;
```

Comment: Genial! Muchisimas gracias por esta otra forma de realizarlo. Te consulto, que ventajas tiene realizarlo de la manera en la que propones?

Comment: Transforms fueron creadas para este tipo de cosas, cuando tienes que manipular la data de alguna forma antes de servirla

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es simple: no estás ejecutando tu método particular `toJson` al enviar el resultado al cliente:

Actualmente tienes:

```js
usuario.save((err, usuarioDB) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      error: err
    });
  }
  usuarioDB.password = undefined;
  res.json({
    ok: true,
    usuario: usuarioDB
  });
});
```

Por lo tanto estás enviando todos los campos de `usuarioDB` sin el campo `password` que has quitado manualmente. En ningún momento has usado tu método `toJson`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo que debes hacer es invocar al método al momento de enviar la data, por ejemplo:

```js
usuario.save((err, usuarioDB) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      error: err
    });
  }
  //usuarioDB.password = undefined;  <- este paso ya no es necesario
  res.json({
    ok: true,
    usuario: usuarioDB.toJson() // <- aqui invoco al método
  });
});
```

De esta forma los datos enviados serán los que devuelve el método `toJson`.